# Merge color vertices at center rather than at one vertex?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, opengl-compat

I'm trying to make a color swatch tool, where you give it n colors and it makes a n-gon with those colors merging at the center.

So far it just makes an n-gon(without specifying colors, it randomly generates them for now).

However the colors don't merge at the center but rather a single vertex.

Is there any fix to this?

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
float randfloat(){
  float r = ((float)(rand() % 10))/10;
  return r;
}
int main() {
  int side_count;
  std::cout<<"Type the no. of sides: "<<std::endl;
  std::cin>>side_count;
  srand(time(NULL));
  std::cout<<randfloat()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<randfloat()<<std::endl;
  float rs[side_count];
  float gs[side_count];
  float bs[side_count];
  for (int i=0;i<side_count;i++)
  {
    rs[i] = randfloat();
    gs[i] = randfloat();
    bs[i] = randfloat();
  }
  GLFWwindow* window;
  if (!glfwInit())
    return 1;
  window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "Window", NULL, NULL);
  if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    return 1;
  }
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  if(glewInit()!=GLEW_OK)
    std::cout<<"Error"<<std::endl;

  while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.11f,0.15f,0.17f,1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      //glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);glVertex3f(-0.5f,0.0f,0.0f);
      for(int i=0; i<side_count;i++)
      {
        float r = rs[i];
        float g = gs[i];
        float b = bs[i];
        float x = 0.5f * sin(2.0*M_PI*i/side_count);
        float y = 0.5f * cos(2.0*M_PI*i/side_count);
        glColor3f(r,g,b);glVertex2f(x,y);
      }
    glEnd();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
  }
  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rabbid's code technically fits your requirements, but I doubt its usefulness as a color picker. The issue is that for three colors (a triangle) you want to mix the colors using barycentric coordinates (not what that code does). For more than three colors the barycentric coordinates are ambiguous, making such a 2-d picker ill-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you've to do is to add a new point to the `GL_POLYGON` primitive, in the center of the circular shape:

```cpp
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex2f(0, 0);

for(int i=0; i <= side_count; i++)
{
    float r = rs[i % side_count];
    float g = gs[i % side_count];
    float b = bs[i % side_count];
    float x = 0.5f * sin(2.0*M_PI*i/side_count);
    float y = 0.5f * cos(2.0*M_PI*i/side_count);
    glColor3f(r, g, b);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
}

glEnd();
```

Note, you've to define the color for the center point. In the code snippet, I've chosen (0.5, 0.5, 0.5).
Instead of `GL_POLYGON`, [`GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives)  can be used, too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me find `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`, but as to the center color would it be possible to mix all the colors, like in a rgb triangle the center is white

Comment: @ChrisMathewGeorge You can choose white by `glColor3f(1, 1, 1)`, but it is not possible to mix all the color automatically

Comment: I did something like changing it into `glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)`. Will this be good.

Comment: @ChrisMathewGeorge Then the center of the shape is black. Not you can calculate the average color on CPU and use it.